# Past participle of "flaw"

Tags: verbs, past-participles, conjugation, irregular

According to [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flaw#Verb), the past participle of "flaw" is *flawed*, and *[flawn](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flawn#Verb)* is not mentioned as being a valid alternative. However, the past participle of "draw" is *[drawn](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/draw#Verb)*. I know that Modern English is irregular with regard to many forms and conjugations (for better or worse), but at first glance it is logical that the past participle form should be *flawn*, and not *flawed*. In short, what is the correct conjugation of the past participle for the verb *flaw*?

Answer (score 15):

Well, to start with, *flaw* is not really a verb; it's a noun, and nouns don't have past participles.

Like practically any noun, however, it can be "[Verbed](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Verbing.pdf)" (as Calvin calls it; linguists call it [Zero-Derivation, or Conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_%28linguistics%29)), resulting in a causative verb *to flaw*, meaning 'cause to have a flaw'. 
It's not very common, though -- I mean, how likely do these sentences sound?

- *Don't flaw that cantata!*
- *I will flaw every stone I find.*
- *She really enjoyed flawing those.*

However, common or not, all Zero-Derived verbs are regular, and that means that the principal parts of *flaw* are

> ***flaw, flawed, flawed***.

*Draw* and *fly*, however, **are** verbs, and **are** irregular, to boot. **Their** principal parts are

> ***draw, drew, drawn***

and

> ***fly, flew, flown***

There are vowel shifts here, which is one mark of irregularity; the past participle inflection is another. 
The ***-n*** suffix for past participle goes back to Germanic. In Modern German, the past participles of "strong" (i.e, irregular) verbs always end in *-en*, while the past participles of "weak" (regular) verbs always end in *-t*. In English, regular verbs have collapsed both the Past and the Past Participle inflections to *-ed*, while irregular verbs vary all over the lot.

Comment: Why did you capitalize the term "*verbed*"?

Comment: Because I capitalized the other terms.

Comment: Would you also say that ‘bottle’, ‘catalogue’, ‘oil’, ‘brake’, ‘referee’ and ‘bicycle’ are not really verbs?

Comment: Does one of them have an irregular conjugation?  "All the books here have now been catalogen."

Comment: They are primarily nouns, and secondarily derived verbs. And the derived verbs are all regular. They're not all causatives, of course; _oil_ is provisional, and _brake_ is applicative, for instance. There are a lot of semantic categories that derived verbs can fall into.

Comment: It it looks like a verb, if it inflects like a verb and if it functions as a verb, then it is a verb.

Comment: That's right. But there are a lot of differences between derived and basic verbs; only basic verbs can be irregular, for one thing.

Answer (score 4):

The only past participle of *flaw* in the whole of the OED is *flawed*.

Comment: Is the OED solely authoritative when it comes to Modern English?

Comment: It is not. You have to use your own judgement in interpreting what you find there, and weigh it against what other sources tell you. That said, there is no reference work on English words and their history that is more compehensive.

Comment: I've searched several corpora (BNC, COCA etc.) and not a single one has "flawn" as a verb.

Answer (score 3):

There's no more to it than what you've stated.  The past participle form of *flaw* is in fact *flawed*, and never *flawn*.  It's not uncommon for English verbs to have differing conjugations.

Comment: I didn't necessarily answer my own question. Maybe a dictionary exists that does list a variant form for the past participle.

Comment: Even if one did, it would be obscure and obsolete.  Since you're asking for the "correct conjugation", you shouldn't worry about obscure variants.

Comment: [Never say never](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/never_say_never).